# Cross-platform (Mac & Windows) desktop app with DRM support

Tags: cross-platform, desktop-application, drm, widevine

Can anyone suggest me options for developing a cross-platform desktop application (MacOS & Windows8.1+) which supports DRM playback.

I have looked into [ElectronJS](https://electronjs.org/) (does not support DRM [inbuilt](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/testing-widevine-cdm)), Used [castlabs](https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases) fork of Electron with VMP enabled Widevine DRM support but getting a production ready license cert from Google Widevine takes ages.

So looking into more options where DRM playback (PlayReady, Widevine & FairPlay) can be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know of the Castlabs Electron fork. I don't think you are going to find a better solution really.

You can always license PlayReady and port it to all the platforms you want to support, the licensing for that is straightforward but the actual implementation would require a large amount of effort. It would likely be easier to just try and embed Chromeless Safari and Chromeless Edge on the respective platforms.